# SQL Join 3 tables and get latest purchase date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find the exact date of the last purchase a customer has made.

I have a table that contains customers information.
I have another table that lists the purchases they made withing 6 months
and another table which lists the purchases they made older than 6 months.

1. Customers

> ```
> |customer_id|fname|lname  |
> |     1     |John |Doe    |
> |     2     |Pete |Jones  |
> |     3     |Jane |Evans  |
> |     4     |Alan |Malcom |
> |     5     |Ron  |Ray    |
> ```

2. PurchaseHistory (purchases within 6 months)

> ```
> |customer_id|product_id|purchase_date      |
> |     1     |00001     |2018-02-01 11:35:14|
> |     1     |00002     |2018-03-02 12:25:23|
> |     3     |00003     |2018-04-03 13:15:34|
> |     1     |00001     |2018-05-04 14:45:45|
> |     3     |00002     |2018-06-05 15:55:24|
> |     2     |00001     |2018-07-01 16:05:41|
> ```

3. PurchaseHistoryArchive (purchases older than 6 months)

> ```
> |customer_id|product_id|purchase_date      |
> |     1     |00001     |2017-02-01 11:35:14|
> |     1     |00002     |2017-03-02 12:25:23|
> |     3     |00003     |2017-04-03 13:15:34|
> |     4     |00001     |2017-05-04 14:45:45|
> |     3     |00002     |2017-06-05 15:55:24|
> |     5     |00001     |2017-07-01 16:05:41|
> ```

The result I want should ideally look like this:

> ```
> |customer_id|fname|lname  |purchase_date      |
> |     1     |John |Doe    |2018-05-04 14:45:45|
> |     2     |Pete |Jones  |2018-07-01 16:05:41|
> |     3     |Jane |Evans  |2018-06-05 15:55:24|
> |     4     |Alan |Malcom |2017-05-04 14:45:45|
> |     5     |Ron  |Ray    |2017-07-01 16:05:41|
> ```

OR if this is not possible then something like this perhaps:

> ```
> |customer_id|fname|lname  |purchase_date_new  |purchase_date_old  |
> |     1     |John |Doe    |2018-05-04 14:45:45|2017-05-04 14:45:45|
> |     2     |Pete |Jones  |2018-07-01 16:05:41|2017-03-02 12:25:23|
> |     3     |Jane |Evans  |2018-06-05 15:55:24|2017-06-05 15:55:24|
> |     4     |Alan |Malcom |NULL               |2017-05-04 14:45:45|
> |     5     |Ron  |Ray    |NULL               |2017-07-01 16:05:41|
> ```

I can query the PurchaseHistory and PurchaseHistoryArchive tables separately against the customers table using the below code, but ideally I want to do it in one query.

```
SELECT c.customer_id, c.fname, c.lname, p1.purchase_date, p2.purchase_date
FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN purchaseHistory p1 ON (c.customer_id, = p1.customer_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN purchaseHistory p2 ON (c.customer_id = p2.customer_id AND 
    (p1.purchase_date < p2.purchase_date OR p1.purchase_date = p2.purchase_date AND p1.customer_id < p2.customer_id))
WHERE p2.customer_id IS NULL
ORDER BY customer_id desc;
```

Any ideas please??

Comment: What's the purpose of the WHERE clause?

Comment: Your description of the problem and your results do not match.  Why are you returning multiple dates?  Also, tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: union select PurchaseHistory and PurchaseHistory. Join the union result with your Customers table and you fill be fine to go. Note1: Your SQL and your table names do not match, there is no table named Purchases. Note2: You know you can not have two columns with the same name in your select, right?

Comment: I edited my question to correct the table names. Thanks for the quick responses everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate *before* doing the `join`:

```
select c.*,
       coalesce(ph.max_pd, pha.max_id) as max_purchase_date
from customers c left join
     (select ph.customer_id, max(ph.purchase_date) as max_pd
      from PurchaseHistory ph
      group by ph.customer_id
     ) ph
     on c.customer_id = ph.customer_id left join
     (select pha.customer_id, max(pha.purchase_date) as max_pd
      from PurchaseHistory pha
      group by pha.customer_id
     ) pha
     on c.customer_id = pha.customer_id;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I marked this as answer but as a new member it does not mark up. Much appreciated though :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like below, where you don't need to fetch all the rows from archive table.

```
  select p.customer_id, max(p.purchase_date) as last_purchase
  from PurchaseHistory p
  inner join customer c on c.customer_id=p.customer_id
  group by p.customer_id
  union all
  select p.customer_id, max(p.purchase_date) as last_purchase
  from PurchaseHistoryArchive p
  inner join customer c on c.customer_id=p.customer_id
  where not exists(select 1 from PurchaseHistory where customer_id=c.customer_id)
  group by p.customer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT C.*, JQ.purchaseDate FROM CUSTOMERS C 
        OUTER APPLY 
            (SELECT TOP 1 U.purchaseDate FROM (SELECT PH1.purchaseDate 
                                                    FROM PurchasHistory PH1 
                                                    WHERE PH1.Customer_id = C.CustomerId
                                                UNION ALL 
                                                SELECT PH2.purchaseDate 
                                                    FROM PurchasHistoryArchive PH2 
                                                    WHERE PH2.Customer_id = C.CustomerId) U
                                                ORDER BY U.purchaseDate DESC            
            ) JQ
```